# T-SQL: Select data from all tables reverted by INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract data from all tables that were reverted by following query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'ERP_%'
```

I've tried to execute following query, but without success:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'ERP_%')
WHERE STATUS = 'XXX'
```

Looking forward to your assistance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153094/sql-server-how-to-select-from-a-list-of-tables-using-information-schema-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to generate a dynamic SQL statement and execute it:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = N''

-- Dynamic SQL
SELECT @stm = (
   SELECT CONCAT(
        N'SELECT * FROM ',
        QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME),
        N' WHERE [STATUS] = ''XXX''; '
   )
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'ERP_%'
   FOR XML PATH('')
)

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query using dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = '';

select @sql = @sql + 'select * from ' + TABLE_NAME + ' where [status] = ''XXX''; '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME like 'ERP_%';

exec(@sql);
```